# Windows: Swap Drive letters between disks

Tags: windows, windows-10, drive-letter

I currently have 2 drives that I want to swap the drive letters of: D and F. I have a bunch of programs installed on D but I plan on taking out the drive in the near future so I've copied all of the files from D to F.

I was wondering if there is a way to change the F drive's letter to D without messing everything up.

Comment: It will be very easy to mess things up. I suggest not doing this.   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/restore-system-boot-drive-letter

Comment: The utility for this is Disk Management. This is less risky if the drive is not your main, boot drive (usually C:). Here is a Microsoft’s documentation on the process: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-drive-letter

Comment: @John That will be very easy to mess up indeed because my D drive is actually 2 drives in raid 0 and thus don't show up as a single drive. But it isn't risky because neither D nor F are my boot drives and I have backups. Going off of what JG7 said I'm just going to change D to some other letter and then change F to D and hope nothing explodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily swap drive letters with *Disk Management*, but please keep in mind this has some risk and perhaps your programs might not work properly after swapping drive letters.

Don't change the drive letter of your OS partition [`C:`]:

1. Right-click on *This PC* → *Manage* → *Storage* → *Disk Management*
2. Right-click `D:` → *Change drive letter and paths* → *Change* → Assign a third drive letter → *OK*
3. Repeat #2 for `F:`, assigning `D:` as the new letter
4. Change drive letter assigned in #2 to `F:`

Comment: While this works, Windows 10 had initially told me that I would not be able to set another drive to the letter D until I restart my computer which is what lead me to ask this question. However your answer definitely works regardless of what Windows says.

Comment: "_...this has some sort of risk and perhaps your programs might not work properly after swapping drive letters._" For 99% of users, that's simply factually inaccurate, and for those it would apply to, who manually configured programs to use a mount point other than `C:`, they would already be aware they'd need to modify their customizations. "_...Don't change the drive letter of your main drive, which contains the OS (usually `C:`)._" The OP wasn't asking about `C:`, they were asking about `D:` and `F:`, coupled with it's not possible to change `C:`'s mount point since it's baked into the OS.